# laravel In which model should I put an invite method (User oder Invitation)

Tags: php, laravel, model

Given I have two models `User` and `Invitation`

invitation only consists of `user_id, invited_email`

and I have a model method:

```
public function invite(string $email) {
    Invitation::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'invited_email' => $email
    ]);
}
```

Should this be in the Invitation or User model?
It would seem reasonable to be in the User model since it is an action that a user performs. However, my User model becomes very bloated when I follow this strategy for everything, since most actions are related to a user.

Comment: So they're a relationship yeah? an Invitation belongsTo a User?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine to be on the `User` model since you're inviting the current loged in user (`auth()->user()`).

Maybe you can clean up some of that other logic you have on the `User` to another Model or Service that can be worth trying.